# How to make Spring throw an error when a body is provided

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an application with a controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping
    public String handler() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

This controller is not supposed to accept any body. However, when I call the endpoint with a body the body is just ignored. How can I make Spring throw an error when providing a body to an endpoint which accepts none?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 options for you. The first one is to take a parameter with Body and then handle it by yourself:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping
    public String handler(@RequestBody(required = false) String requestBody) {
        if (requestBody != null && !requestBody.isEmpty()) {
            throw new YourException("This endpoint does not accept a request body.");
        }
        return ...;
    }
}
```

and the second one is to consume Mediatype. In this option, Spring will show 'HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException'. Actually, you can add any MediaType:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String handler() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first option seems like a workaround. If the endpoint is not supposed to accept any body, declaring a body as optional and checking that the body was actually not provided seems a bit counterproductive.

The second one will return 415, thus tricking the client into think that it can actually receive a body but with some other media type. Additionally, if you call the endpoint without declaring any media type and with an empty body you will also get a 415.